# @AfterTest selenium annotation getting executed before all the @Test's are executed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have worked on Selenium and TestNG. But I am not an expert. I tried searching a suitable answer for this but could not find. Hence requesting help.

I have a initialization class as below.

```
public class Initialization {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Initialization.class);
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void intiDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        logger.debug("Creating driver");
        DesiredCapabilities dcap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), dcap);
        logger.debug("Driver created");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void closeDriver(){
        logger.debug("Quitting driver");
        if(driver != null){
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
            logger.debug("Driver destroyed");
        }
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
}
```

And then I have 2 test case class file which extends the above class file (as shown below)

```
public class SampleTestCase1 extends Initialization {

    @Test
    public void sampleTest1(){
        System.out.println("getDriver1: "+ getDriver());
        getDriver().get("http://www.google.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void sampleTest2(){
        System.out.println("getDriver2: "+ getDriver());
        getDriver().get("http://www.bing.com");
    }
}

public class SampleTestCase2 extends Initialization {

    @Test
    public void sampleTest3(){
        System.out.println("getDriver3: "+ getDriver());
        getDriver().get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
    }

    @Test
    public void sampleTest4(){
        System.out.println("getDriver4: "+ getDriver());
        getDriver().get("http://www.rediff.com/");
    }
}
```

I am observing that sampleTest3 and sampleTest4 testcases are not being executed because getDriver() is returning null. I believe the driver instance is getting destroyed after I execute sampleTest1 and smapleTest2. I have used @afterTest annotation, hence ideally the driver instance should be destroyed after all the @Test's are executed.

I don't what is going wrong. Can somebody help?.

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Sample.SampleTestCase2.sampleTest3(SampleTestCase2.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:74)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Ideally You should use All four in same class. See the xml file generated. Hope it conatins both classes.

Comment: @KishanPatel Thanks for the reply. But which xml file are you speaking? My testng.xml file looks as shown below:

Comment: @KishanPatel <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >

    <test name="Sample Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="Sample.SampleTestCase1" />
            <class name="Sample.SampleTestCase2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

Comment: Try to keep all in one class and run it once.

Comment: Or else right click on the xml file and then run that xml file.

Comment: Hope you are not running a single class.

Comment: Yes it's work when I put all the Test in one class. But then without putting all of them in one class if I change AfterTest to Aftermethod / AfterClass it work's perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes I did run by testng.xml file by right clicking.

Answer (score 3):

TestNG is not JUnit. Don't missmatch `@BeforeTest/AfterTest` and `@BeforeMethod/AfterMethod`.

> @BeforeTest: 
>   The annotated method will be run before any test method
>   belonging to the classes inside the  tag is run.
>
> @AfterTest:
>   The annotated method will be run after all the test methods belonging
>   to the classes inside the  tag have run.
>
> @BeforeMethod: 
>   The annotated method will be run before each test method.
>
> @AfterMethod:
>   The annotated method will be run after each test method.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have made sure that the class files mentioned are under test tag in the testng.xml file. I have pasted below. Hence all the testcases should run right?

Comment: `<test name="Sample Test">
            <classes>
                <class name="Sample.SampleTestCase1" />
                <class name="Sample.SampleTestCase2" />
            </classes>
        </test>`

Comment: TestNG is not working like that: You will have 2 instances (TestCase1 and TestCase2). Both of them have the `@BeforeTest` method thank to the inheritance BUT only one will be triggered. You have `@BeforeClass` if you want one by class or you need to use ThreadLocal tricks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either:

- Change your annotations to @BeforeClass and @AfterClass respectively
- Change your xml. Put your classes under **test** tag

Hope, you understand what I mean.

Comment: Yes I got it ... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to understand is the TestNG execution order when you execute the tests using the xml file in the following configuration

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
    <test name="Sample Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="Sample.SampleTestCase1" />
            <class name="Sample.SampleTestCase2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Order:

```
@BeforeTest in SampleTestCase1 extends Initialization
    sampleTest1
    sampleTest2
    sampleTest3
    sampleTest4
@AfterTest in SampleTestCase1 extends Initialization
```

Ignored:

```
@BeforeTest in SampleTestCase2 extends Initialization
@AfterTest in SampleTestCase2 extends Initialization
```

This is because you have added SampleTestCase1 and SampleTestCase2 as `<classes>` to the `<test>` in the TestNG xml file. This mean SampleTestCase1 and SampleTestCase2 are part of a single test called `Sample Test`. Eventhough both classes extends Initialization class (you would expect @BeforeTest and @AfterTest getting called for each test class), TestNG only sees 1 @BeforeTest and 1 @AfterTest and 4 test methods.

SampleTest1 and SampleTest2 gets the driver because `@BeforeTest in SampleTestCase1 extends Initialization` is invoked. sampleTest3 and sampleTest4 methods getDriver() method returns null because `@BeforeTest in SampleTestCase2 extends Initialization` is never invoked.

If you add a sysout in the @BeforeTest to print "start" and @AfterTest to print "stop" you would find the following in the console proving the above point.

```
start
getDriver1: FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (8573d6f7-fa66-45bc-9754-1145f5834b82)
getDriver2: FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (8573d6f7-fa66-45bc-9754-1145f5834b82)
getDriver3: null
getDriver4: null
stop

===============================================
Suite1
Total tests run: 4, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

I will add one of the many solutions to make it work as a separate answer as this answer has gotten pretty lengthy!!

Answer (score 0):

Answer continued....

If you would like to open the browser and close it only once Make the driver and the getDriver() method static in the initialization code.

```
public class Initialization {
private static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void intiDriver() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("start");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void closeDriver() {
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("stop");
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
}
```

TestNG.xml

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
    <test name="Sample Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="Sample.SampleTestCase1" />
            <class name="Sample.SampleTestCase2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

If you are Ok with opening the browser multiple times (1 browser/Test class), you can keep the original Initialization class (no need of static drivers) and modify only the TestNG XML file to contain 2 tests.

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
    <test name="Sample Test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="Sample.SampleTestCase1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Sample Test2">
        <classes>
            <class name="Sample.SampleTestCase2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I had taken this approach. But using a static creates problems when I run tests in Parallel (by using option parallel="methods" / parallel = "class". Hence I used a non-static reference.

Comment: If you are looking at parallel execution between test classes, then you would have to define multiple `<test>` in the xml file. Note that the browser will open once per each Test class. I have modified the answer.